# Using the %cd magic command in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook where I frequently use the `%cd` magic command. At the top of this notebook I set a bookmark (`%bookmark 'base_dir'`) so that I can easily return to my starting directory (via `%cd -b 'base_dir'`).

Is there an easier way to return to the starting directory (i.e. the directory where the running *.ipynb exists)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just switching between the starting folder and subfolder, "%cd -"
will work.
Each time you run it it directs you to the previous directory, which means if you run it two times you will stay in the current directory.