# How do I change path directory in Jupyter lab?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How do I change initial path directory in Jupyter lab, when i want to get a file via "~/"?

[image]

Have tried to generate config, and then change some parameters but only got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [the `%cd` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd) to change the working directory. And then to set up using tab completion, you'd start by typing `./` before hitting tab at the place where you want to choose your CSV file.

In the demonstration set-up for the screenshot below I made a `test` directory in the root (home) location and made two CSV files in there.

Using `%cd test` first I am then able to use tab completion to get the option to select one of the two CSV files:
[image]

I probably should have included running `pwd` to 'print the working directory`after I ran the`%cd test` command to demonstrate things more fully.

Before I executed the command `%cd test`, the tab-completion was showing the root (home directory) when I tried for tab completion.

[image]

---

---

The tilde symbol (`~`) always means the HOME directory on the system. It won't change. So you were always specifying to start in `HOME` in your example in your post, **no matter what the current working directory is in the notebook's active namespace**. You want to use relative paths for when the working directory has been adjusted.

---

---

There are more complex settings you can take advantage of using inside the notebook in conjunction with the `%cd` magic.

For example, [this post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677797/using-the-cd-magic-command-in-jupyter-notebooks) shows how you can use the [%boookmark](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-bookmark) magic to set assign a directory to a bookmark setting and then  you can more easily switch around to various directories using `%cd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change file directory like that.

```
import shutil

File= r'C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\Somewhereidonotknow\example.csv'
Whereyou_want= r'C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\example.csv'

shutil.move(File, Whereyou_want)
```

Comment: Yes you're right actually I meant to import. It'd be better I remove that part @Wayne thanks.